# Banana Drop - C# Game

Tags: c#, performance, time, 2d, pixel

I'm working on a 2d game. In it bananas(`picturBox`) drops from the top of the screen and you have to catch them otherwise it hits the ground and you lose points. To animate the banana, I change it's **Y-Location** using a `timer` which has an interval of **5ms**(Smooth animation).

The **Y-Drop Speed** is changed based on the resolution of the screen. Since the banana is moving **1px** every **5ms** on base resolution which is **720**, it needs to change speed to take same time on different resolutions.

Code:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double xNanas = nanas.Location.X;
    double yNanas = nanas.Location.Y;
    yNanas += 1 * this.Height / 720;
    nanas.Location = new Point((int)xNanas, (int)yNanas);
    nanas.Refresh();
}
```

**Problem:**

**1.** When the resolution is changed to a small number for ex. 800x600. The double converts to int and the banana doesn't move even though (1 * 600 / 720) rounded is 1.

**2.** Since the speed is always rounded the time it takes for the banana to hit the ground varies drastically! 16.7 on 1920x1080 and 10.6 on 1280x720. How would I make it same?

**Tried:**

Changing the interval rather than the speed. It still doesn't hit the ground at exact same time. I can't change the interval to a large number as that makes the animation choppy.

Comment: You need to look in to implementing delta time

Comment: You're doing integer math. Try `yNanas += 1 * this.Height / 720d`

Comment: @SimpleVar Thank you! That solved problem #1 but what about problem #2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not right, as you can see it will vary speed because int does not have decimal and thus the speed changes.

An easy solution is to store in a class the positions as doubles and do all the logic in double, then you just cast the double in the class to int after doing all the calculations and set it to the picture box position, in this way the double will increment at the same speed independently of the screen size.

Here is an example with float logic (enough for your needs):

```
PointF realPosition = PointF.Empty; //Initialize it to the real position of the pb.

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    realPosition.Y += 1.0f * this.Height / 720.0f; //note the .0f to instruct the compiler these must be float operations
    nanas.Location = Point.Round(realPosition);
    nanas.Refresh();
}
```

Also you have another source of error, the Forms timers aren't exact, if the UI is busy it will vary it's speed, for a real game the normal is not to use a timer, but a loop and check the time elapsed and multiply it by the speed in seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I don't understand your answer. I want the speed to change because when the resolution changes the speed should reflect with it so that the banana hits the ground at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I understand, and in my post what I say is your time are changing because the divider has decimals and you're discarding them because the int math logic, you must to use double logic.

Comment: It says `operator += cannot be applied to operands of type 'pointF' and 'double'`

Comment: It says cannot convert double to float, so I removed the decimals and then ran it and the time it takes doesn't match again.

Comment: because you converted it again to integers, sorry but i'm not in a windows machine, let me correct it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102815/discussion-between-muhammad-ali-and-gusman).