# How to make a magic chest in the game with c# windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, random, windows-forms-designer

I am making item drop game and I am trying to make a magic chest.

When the chest comes down and touches the player, there are two random possibilities: either a loss or an advantage in the score.

The chest has to go down every 10 sec.

I wrote the code like this but the game never started after that.

(I think the problem is the code of random )

```
foreach (Control X in this.Controls) 
{
    while (X.Tag == "kah" && player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(chest.Bounds)) 
    {
        chest.Top = -600;
        Index = magicchest.Next(0, 2);
        if (Index == 0) 
        {
            score -= 3;
        } else 
        {
            score += 3;
        }
        while (seconds % 10 == 0) 
        {
            chest.Left = rnd2.Next(213, this.ClientSize.Width - chest.Width);
            chest.Top = rnd2.Next(0, 700) * -1;
            chest.Top += compspeed;
        }
    }
}
```

```
private void resetGame() 
{
    timer1.Start();
    gametime.Start()
                do 
    {
        chest.Left = rnd.Next(23, this.ClientSize.Width -chest.Width);
        chest.Top = rnd.Next(0, 670) * -1;
    }
    while (seconds % 10 == 0);
    chest.Top += compspeed;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest starting by learning about [timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). Or use a framework intended for gaming, like unity3d.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the `gametime.Start() do` part (Missing end-of-line character), and the code you posted is horribly bad formatted. Does it actually compile on your side?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35247414/16764901 Check out a similar post trying to control random drops with the `timer` control. Edit your question after editing and we'll continue to answer your question.